# how print_parts() function work in composing program chapter2.3

Tags: python, tree, partition-problem

in book composing program [chapter 2.3](http://composingprograms.com/pages/23-sequences.html), there is a function print_part() makes me confused (whole code [here](http://cs61a.org/assets/slides/11.py)):

```
>>> def print_parts(tree, partition=[]):
        if is_leaf(tree):
            if root(tree):
                print(' + '.join(partition))
        else:
            left, right = branches(tree)
            m = str(root(tree))
            print_parts(left, partition + [m])
            print_parts(right, partition)

>>> print_parts(partition_tree(6, 4))
4 + 2
4 + 1 + 1
3 + 3
3 + 2 + 1
3 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 2 + 2
2 + 2 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
```

this function print all the ways using  parts up to 4 to partition 6. I've understand how the partition algorithm works in partition_tree() and have no problem to understand a partition tree:

```
                   4
       _________________________
       |                       |
       4                       3
   _______                    _____
   |     |                    |    |
   ..   ...                ...    ...
```

but I still don't know how to print partition ways from a partition tree. especially these lines:

```
print(' + '.join(partition))

print_parts(left, partition + [m])
print_parts(right, partition)
# why call twice? and the recursion here didn't looks like the
# way the print_parts() called in the beginning.
```

update:

> recursion here didn't looks like the way the print_parts() called in the beginning.

take an simpler args as example to illustrate my confusion:

```
>>> print_parts(partition_tree(3, 2))
2 + 1
1 + 1 + 1
```

the partition tree is:

```
                         2
           --------------------------------
          2                               1
    ----------------           ------------------------
   F               1           1                     F
               ------        ------------
              T    F         1          F
                           -------
                          T      F
```

or

```
[2, [2, [False], [1, [True], [False]]], [1, [1, [1, [True], [False]],[False]],[False]]]
```

the above list is first pass into the func print_parts() as trees's value.

when going to this line:

```
print_parts(left, partition + [m])
```

the left value is

```
[[2, [False], [1, [True], [False]]], [1, [1, [1, [True], [False]],[False]],[False]]]
```

it's no longer a tree because in the definition the tree should have a structure like: `[node, [branch],[branch]]`. if so, the recursion cannot works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you understand the algorithm but maybe not the Python code.

`print(' + '.join(partition))` is just formatting a list into the output format that you see. For example, it turns the list `[3, 2, 1]` into the string `'3 + 2 + 1'`.

Then the reason the way `print_parts` can be called in a way that "doesn't look the same" as the original call is that the method definition allows for an optional second argument. If the second option is not explicitly provided, it is by default set to an empty list. That's what `partition=[]` in the function definition does.

As for why it's being called "twice", it's just that at each step of the recursion, we're branching into two branches (left and right), and then recursively processing both the left side and the right side.

**Update (reply to your update):**

The confusion stems from this line where Python can assign multiple variables at once:

```
left, right = branches(tree)
```

Since `branches(tree)` is a list of length 2, the 2 elements get assigned to `left` and `right` respectively.

So it is not true what you said:

> the left value is
>
> ```
> [[2, [False], [1, [True], [False]]], [1, [1, [1, [True], [False]],[False]],[False]]]
> ```

But instead:

```
left, right = branches(partition_tree(3, 2))
print left
> [2, [False], [1, [True], [False]]]
print right
> [1, [1, [1, [True], [False]], [False]], [False]]
```

Comment: to better illustrate my problem, I've updated the question above. looks like I have some problem about how the program processes the tree list structure. could you please help me again? many thanks!